# removeCurrent only delete in datagridview but not in database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I am using vb.net and ms access for database.  i have 1 delete button but it not working as I want it to be. it just delete current row in data grid view, it does not delete the data in database. this is my code:

```
Test123BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
```

and i also tried this code. it works on another program i'm developing  but didnt work for this program.

```
Test123BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
Test123TableAdapter.Update(ABCDEDataSet.Test123)
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have `DELETE` command set in your data adapter? You need to define your question better. Including types of objects that you're displaying here

Comment: Of course the first code snippet only deletes from the grid and not the database.  That's exactly what it is supposed to do.  The second code snippet is what you need because the first line deletes the row locally and then the second line saves the local changes back to the database. If that's not working then it's because you did something wrong somewhere.  In order to know what you did wrong, we need to have all the relevant information.  What actually happens when you execute your code is ALWAYS relevant.  Is there an error message?  If not, how do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use update Option in Delete Button
but **Add an Update button** to update the records in Databse
That's What I have done